# How to categorize load tests for filtering during TFS2015 build execution

Tags: tfsbuild, load-testing, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are planning to run a number of load/performance tests during TFS2015 build execution using "Run Functional Tests" vNext step, on-premises.

We are planning to run them under different categories, namely: smoke, stress, performance and capacity planning.

Trying to organise our tests into categories, however, seems to pose a problem:

- Even if we convert our performance tests to coded web tests, we still cannot apply the "Test Category" attribute (strictly speaking intended for Unit and Coded UI tests), as there are no test methods to apply it to. This means we cannot filter our tests using the "Test Filter criteria" field in our "Run Functional Tests" build step.
- Microsoft "[don't recommend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx) linking load tests or web tests to test cases", which means we cannot even group our tests under a Test Plan (which then could be used with a "Test Selection = Test Plan" execution option in the build step.

**Is grouping load/performance tests at project level (so we basically have a dll for each intended category) the only option for "categorising" them? If not, what is it?**

On a related note, what is the recommended practice for organising load/performance tests **with respect to "execution options"** in "Run Functional Tests" vNext build step, if any?

Answer (score 0):

As we know, only Unit Test can apply the "Test Category" attribute. There is no way to group categories for web tests.

As an alternative, you can consider copying the test binaries to different Test Drop Location and specifying the test assemblies.